# Node.js Rest Api and Socket.io and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

I would like to do a hybrid rest api with some socket event.
For my app I use Express and socket io.

This is my code :

index.ts

```js
import {App} from "./app";



async function main() {
    const app = new App(3000);
    await app.listen();

}

main();
```

app.ts

```js
import express, {Application} from 'express';
import { createServer, Server } from 'http';
import sio  from 'socket.io';
import morgan  from 'morgan';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';

import { genericError,erroHandler } from "./routes/errorHandler.routes";
//Middleware
import {corsManager} from "./middlewares/cors-manager.middleware";


export class App {
    public static readonly PORT:number = 3000;
    private app:Application;
    private _server:Server;
    private io:any;
    constructor(private port?: number | string){
        this.createApp();
        this.settings();
        this.createServer();
        this.sockets();
        //this.middlewares();
        //this.routes();
    }

    private createApp(): void {
        this.app = express();
    }
    private createServer(): void {
        this._server = createServer(this.app);
    }

    settings(){
        this.app.set('port', this.port || process.env.PORT || App.PORT);

    }

    private sockets(): void {
        this.io = sio(this._server);
    }




    middlewares(){

        this.app.use(morgan('dev'));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
        this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
        //corse handler
        this.app.use(corsManager)

    }

    routes(){

        //error handler
        this.app.use(genericError);
        this.app.use(erroHandler);


    }

    async listen(){
        this._server=await this._server.listen(this.app.get('port'),()=>{
            console.log('Server on port %s', this.app.get('port'));
        });
        this.io.on('connect', (socket: any) => {
            console.log('Connected client on port %s.', this.port);


            socket.on('disconnect', () => {
                console.log('Client disconnected');
            });
        });
    }

    get server(): Server {
        return this._server;
    }
}
```

The server start on port 3000 and works fine but when I try to connect to it with a socket client, i use "smart websocket client" it's a chrome extension at following url:

ws://localhost:3000/

I retrieve this error:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Please can you help me

Sorry for my English

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Socket.io - failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665840/socket-io-failed-connection-closed-before-receiving-a-handshake-response)

Comment: Yes sorry.. It's my question

Comment: Problem solved ???

Comment: I saw this example but it's not solved my problem